How can I find why a post was deleted?
I was reading the React Native questions to help and answer, then I saw an answer was deleted, and I couldn't find any reason for its deletion!
Wouldn't it be better if deletions required a mandatory reason to inform future visitors?

Most users can't see deleted answers and the post was deleted by a moderator so the author likely was mod messaged.

@ThomA, Is there any way to know what was the reason?

Well, the Qt (Question) currently has a Bounty, and bountied Qt's often attract ChatGPT-generated Answers, so that was probably the reason that Answer got deleted... (Just a guess..., you can probably get more "hints" by looking at the Profile of the User (Answerer), like if they have very low Rep, which Tag(s) they usually answer and are maybe suspended for 1 week or 1 month...)

@chivracq The answer was given before the bounty, but yes, it surely has an AI vibe.

Most users don't even see deleted answers, you have to have a fairly high rep to see them.

Yeah @chivracq, You're right. After your comment, I read it again and really it feels like AI literature. Also, moderators have got many good tools. For example, they can see the duration of the user's answer. Most cheaters copy/paste the answer from AI websites.

Why is the statement about the answer being deleted repeated twice? If you provided a screenshot of the deleted answer more users could weigh in on the possible reasons

The edits were fine; stop rolling back. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Dear @Zoe-Savethedatadump, Your edit is fine, but as a post owner, I can have my own idea about my own question. The last edition before your edition did change my question pattern completely. And I rejected it.

@AmerllicA "The last edition before your edition did change my question pattern completely" It changed the "pattern" by removing repetition. That's objectively an improvement; no one wants to read the same thing twice. As the post author you have a right to have your meaning preserved. Repetition does not qualify as meaning.

"Your edit is fine, but [...] The last edition before your edition did change my question pattern completely". All Zoe did was roll the question back to the version you objected to, so both of those statements can't possibly be true.

@TylerH, Thanks for mentioning this important thing. For sure I won't do it. You're completely right.

You can't, and that's by design.
If it was deleted by a moderator, you can assume there was a moderation related reason, and the user was likely informed directly somehow. Users do not need to know about moderation actions against other users.
In the more general case of a post deleted by regular, non-diamond users; the general reasons for delete votes are not finding any redeemable value in a post, nor seeing a way for a post to become useful. No other reason or justification would be useful in those cases.
If the post was deleted by regular users casting delete-votes, and you disagree with the deletion, you could always cast your own undelete vote.
